# Unsure how this jQuery function works

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I came across this function recently, I am unsure what the first few lines do.

Could someone possibly explain it to me?

Cheers

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.ui.dialog.prototype.options, {
     create: function(event) { doSomthing(event); }
});

function doSomthing(event) {

    STUFF
}
```

Comment: `jQuery.extend` - Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

Comment: Copying and pasting directly from the docs isn't really very helpful all of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is a jquery function that merges objects together, overwriting any object keys with newer 'versions'.

```
// Will overwrite the name property. Output in this case is 'john'
// as it overwrites 'dave'
$.extend({name : "dave"}, {name : 'john'});
```

In the case of the example code you gave, `$.extend` is overwriting a prototype object in a jQueryUI dialog widget with a different function, thus changing how the 'dialog' widget behaves when it is created.

Comment: No problem. Just noticed what this is actually doing... it is creating a global 'create' callback for all dialog widgets. Same applies it isn't, in fact, modifying any of the dialog widgets core code.

Answer (score 3):

1. [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) - Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.
2. `jQuery.ui.dialog.prototype.options` is shared field `options` for all ui dialogs. More info about prototype inheritance [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

Answer (score 1):

It binds call of `doSomthing` to the `create` event of the `jQuery.ui.dialog` or the `jQuery.ui.dialog.prototype.options`.

So `doSomthing` might be called when you create dialog or option. Not sure if creation of the option is implemented.